# Output stream for generic container

Tags: c++, templates, ostream

I have created this template function:

```
// Output stream for container of type C
template<class C>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const C& c) {
    os << "[";
    for (auto& i : c) {
        os << i;
        if (&i != &c.back()) os << ", ";
    }
    os << "]" << endl;
    return os;
}
```

but I have this error:

> error: use of overloaded operator '<<' is ambiguous (with operand
>   types 'std::ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream') and 'const char [2]')

The error is in the first line of the body of the function.

Comment: You really shouldn't provide unconstrained templates like that.  You also shouldn't overload operators for types you don't own.  If it were me, I would make a generic `print` or `stringify` function and use that to print/return a string able to be printed.

Comment: You have provided a brief description of what happens what you compile the shown code: an error message. Your narrative ends at this point, and what seems to be missing from your narrative is an actual question. What is your specific question?

Comment: I noted that if v is a STL container I can't "cout << v" then I want an overload of operator<<.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This declaration

```
template<class C>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const C& c)
```

is a match for any type. In particular, when you call inside that operator

```
os << "[";
os << i;
os << "]" << endl;
```

For all this calls your operator is a match in addition to the already existing output operators for strings and `endl`.

Don't provide operators for types you don't own. Instead you can write a

```
void print(const my_container&);
```

or use a tag to resolve ambiguity. For example you could use a

```
template <typename T>
struct pretty_printed_container {
    const T& container;
};

template <typename T>
pretty_printed_container<T> pretty_print(const T& t) { return {t};}
```

modify your output operator accordingly

```
template<class T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const pretty_printed_container<T>& c) {
    os << "[";
    for (const auto& i : c.container) {
        os << i;
        if (&i != &c.container.back()) os << ", ";
    }
    os << "]" << std::endl;
    return os;
}
```

And then use it like this

```
int main() {
    std::vector<int> x{1,2,3,4,5};
    std::cout << pretty_print(x);
}
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: That `pretty_print` is very elegant

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to `boost` library and you don't want to use `pretty_printed_container` you can implement the following:

```
#include <boost/spirit/home/support/container.hpp>

template <typename CharT, typename Traits, typename Container,
          std::enable_if_t<boost::spirit::traits::is_container<Container>::value, int> = 0>
std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& operator<<(std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& os, const Container& c) {
    os << "[ ";
    for (const auto& e : c)
        os << e << " ";
    return os << "]";
}
```

In this way you can print directly your containers, even nested containers.

Bonus:
Adding this code you will also be able to print associative containers as `std::map`

```
/// operator<< for printing pair, this is needed to print associative containers.
template <typename T, typename U>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::pair<T, U>& p) {
    return os << "[" << p.first << ", " << p.second << "]";
}
```

For example:

```
int main() {
    std::set<int> set{ 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> nestedVector{ {1, 2}, {3, 4} };
    std::map<int, std::string> map{ {1, "one"}, {2, "two"}, };

    std::cout << set << '\n';
    std::cout << nestedVector << '\n';
    std::cout << map << '\n';
}
```

Will output:

```
[ 1 2 3 4 ]
[ [ 1 2 ] [ 3 4 ] ]
[ [1, one] [2, two] ]
```